# Need to bring back information on intermediate model with terminal model on Rails has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, include, has-many-through, named-scope

I have the following models:

school.rb

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :offers
  has_many :players, :through => :offers

  has_many :teammembers, :class_name => 'Offer', :conditions => ["on_roster = \'t\'"]
  has_many :teamplayers, :through => :teammembers, :source => :player
```

player.rb

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :offers, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :sr, lambda { 
    where("(players.year = ? and players.redshirt = 't') or (players.year = ? and players.redshirt = 'f')", (Time.now + 8.months - 5.years).year, (Time.now + 8.months - 4.years).year)
```

}

offer.rb

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school
    belongs_to :player

    validates_uniqueness_of :school_id, :scope => [:player_id]
```

Then in my schools_controller I have

schools_controller.rb

```
def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id], :include => [{:offers => :player}])
  @seniors = @school.teamplayers.sr
```

My issue is that I need to display a field from the offers model that is associated to the relationship between the School and the Player.  Currently I'm performing an additional query in the view to get this field.

schools/show.haml.html

```
- @srpg.each do |player|
  = Offer.find_by_school_id_and_player_id(@school.id, player.id).status
```

Obviously this is causing a N+1 issue, but I can't seem to figure out a way to bring back both the offer.status and the player.* in the same record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work with the offers instead:

```
# in model
class Offer
  belongs_to :player
  scope :of_seniors, includes(:player).where('player.kind = "senior"')
end

# in controller
@seniors_offers = @school.offers.of_seniors

# in view
- for offer in @seniors_offers
  = offer.player.name
  = offer.status
- end
```

Comment: When I attempt to do what you outlined above, I get NoMethodError:   Offer Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."school_id" = 1
undefined method `include' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ffd2bed24e0>

Comment: OK, so I played around with it a bit and if I use "includes" instead of "include" and ":player" instead of ":players" it will return what I need.  My issue now is how to create "of_seniors" since the scope ":sr" is dependent on the player model.

Comment: thanks for the update, I'm getting a syntax error with your recommended scope definition. 
`/Users/paulpettengill/rails/recruits/app/models/offer.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
  scope :of_seniors, :includes(:player)`

Comment: it's `includes(:player)` not `:includes(:player)` (no ":")!

Comment: make sure it does an inner join, otherwise force it: `joins(:player).includes(:player).where(...)`

Comment: Thank you very much!  Just curious, is there a way to do this without breaking the law of demeter, and having the offer model see into the player model.  Ideally, I would think I could somehow reference the scope :sr defined in the player model, rather than defining the scope in the Offer model based on a property of the player model.

Comment: You are not breaking the law of demeter, you just query for offers of seniors.